# PhpStorm - 'Expression expected' and 'Switch language to React' when passing PHP to Vue-component

Tags: php, vue.js, phpstorm

I'm getting two errors:

> Expression expected

[image: Expression expected - PhpStorm]

and

> Switch language version to React JSX

[image: Switch language version to React JSX]

... in PhpStorm, when I try and pass code from PHP to a Vue-component.

I have the Vue-plugin active. How do I get PhpStorm to stop complaining about this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html)? Try writing something like

```
/** @lang php */
```

or

```
// language=php
```

on the line preceding `:images="..."`